# Add and remove fragments frequently

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity and it consists of two fragments. The app switches between one of these fragments very frequently. I am using code like this to switch between fragments,

```
fragmentTransaction
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left)
                .remove(fragment2)
                .add(R.id.common_container, fragment1)
                .commit();
```

The above code removes fragment2 and adds fragment1. The above code works fine but when I try to switch between fragments frequently an exception showing this trace is coming up,`E/AndroidRuntime( 8809): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1054)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1869)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2067)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:912)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8809):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)`

I know that i can use replace instead of adding and removing, but there are other fragments where i cannot replace because the container is different.

Can anyone help me ?

Edit:
Even replacing fragment also causes this exception

Comment: Can't you just replace instead of remove then add again?

Comment: I sometimes need to show and hide a fragment very frequently. I cannot use hide and show methods because the contents of the fragment might change when I switch between. `.add()` ensures that the fragment onCreateView is called